# Importing Excel Data using Oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am using the following code to display the Excel Data into DataGrid using Oledb. But I am getting an error `Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.`

Can anybody tell me where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\testing.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]");
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        this.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've neglected to assign your connection to the command object.

Move this below conn.Open();

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
```

Comment: Cool,,, nice catch... But its just loading blank page instead of my content. I have lots of content in my Excel Sheet but its not showing the content.